# How to set an option, using let, for the current buffer (vim)?

Tags: vim

In vimlanguage, you can set options for the current buffer only using `setlocal`.
However, I need to set a more complex expression than just a literal, which isn't possible with `setlocal`.

I currently have `let &formatprg=s:prgpath." ".a:args`, but this sets the formatprg for all buffers, which is not what I want.
How would I set the formatprg like above, only for the current buffer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `let &l:option` instead of `let &option` to only change the local value, like `setlocal option`. Similarly, `let &g:option` would only set the global value, like `setglobal option`. See [`:help :let-option`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let-option) for more information.

Note that `formatprg` in particular is global (no "local to buffer" in [its help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'formatprg')).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I have two windows open, and run `let &l:formatprg="hey"`, the `&l:formatprg` in the other window gets changed as well.

Comment: That's because `formatprg` is global only; `setlocal` wouldn't work on it either.

Comment: Ah, that explains! It's weird though. I need formatprg to be set locally, since I wanna use different formatprgs for different filetypes.

Comment: Would `formatexpr`, which is local, work in your case? If not, you could set up an `autocmd` to change `formatprg` on `BufRead,BufEnter` for specific filetypes.

Answer (score 1):

Making a global option buffer-local requires changes to Vim's source code. Alternatively, I've just published the [GlobalOptions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4414) that uses autocmds to work around this, and turns any global option into a buffer- or window-local one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've found a post in the mailinglist of vim-dev which requests a patch for this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/vim_dev/formatprg/vim_dev/cFK1UjstyAk/mreb2H4VCtoJ. I think it couldn't hurt to make formatprg local in the next version of vim.